# iOS Parse Push Notifications in Adhoc exported ipa

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I've an application which uses Parse.com push notification service. When I run app on my iPhone with xCode notifications are received well but when I install app with exported ipa with Itunes notifications aren't received.
What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with creating "Production SSL Certificate" in my push notification identifier.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a provisioning profile problem. When you export the .ipa, it uses a particular provisioning profile, and that profile is different for Xcode and for ad-hoc.

To enable push for ad-hoc builds, you can find a detailed list of steps here: [Enabling Apple Push Notifications for ad hoc distribution environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208669/enabling-apple-push-notifications-for-ad-hoc-distribution-environment)

Comment: tnx but didn't help! My problem was something else